# Flink Avro 1.8.1 NoSuchMethodError when running on cluster

Tags: java, maven, avro, apache-flink, flink-cep

We run Flink 1.3.0 CEP jobs and rely on Avro **1.8.1** (LogicalType does not exist in Avro 1.7.7) to serialize complex events (as POJOs). It's working when run from within the IDE (IntelliJ), but when we package the jar-file and deploy it to the cluster we get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema.setLogicalType(Lorg/apache/avro/LogicalType;)V
at org.apache.avro.LogicalType.addToSchema(LogicalType.java:72)
```

However, it seems that we build the jar containing the right Avro package version (1.8.1) regarding the build output.

```
mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar
...
[INFO] Including org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.1 in the shaded jar.
...
```

**Question:** How can we assure that our Flink cluster uses the correct Avro version (1.8.1)?

Our pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.group.flink</groupId>
<artifactId>cep</artifactId>
<version>0.2</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Complex Event Processing</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <flink.version>1.3.0</flink.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <kafka.version>0.10.2.1</kafka.version>
    <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
    <avro.version>1.8.1</avro.version>
    <junit.version>5.0.0-M4</junit.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<!-- 

    Execute "mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar"
    to build a jar file out of this project!

    How to use the Flink Quickstart pom:

    a) Adding new dependencies:
        You can add dependencies to the list below.
        Please check if the maven-shade-plugin below is filtering out your dependency
        and remove the exclude from there.

    b) Build a jar for running on the cluster:
        There are two options for creating a jar from this project

        b.1) "mvn clean package" -> this will create a fat jar which contains all
                dependencies necessary for running the jar created by this pom in a cluster.
                The "maven-shade-plugin" excludes everything that is provided on a running Flink cluster.

        b.2) "mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar" -> This will also create a fat-jar, but with much
                nicer dependency exclusion handling. This approach is preferred and leads to
                much cleaner jar files.
-->

<dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-cep_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- explicitly add a standard loggin framework, as Flink does not (in the future) have
        a hard dependency on one specific framework by default -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>${avro.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.smueller18</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-builder</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.smueller18</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-serialization</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Profile for packaging correct JAR files -->
        <id>build-jar</id>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.version}</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.version}</artifactId>
                <version>${flink.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- disable the exclusion rules -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactSet>
                                    <excludes combine.self="override"></excludes>
                                </artifactSet>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all dependencies
        except flink and it's transitive dependencies. The resulting fat-jar can be executed
        on a cluster. Change the value of Program-Class if your program entry point changes. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- This list contains all dependencies of flink-dist
                                Everything else will be packaged into the fat-jar
                                -->
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-annotations</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-curator-recipes</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-runtime_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-avro_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-batch_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-scala_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-scala-shell_2.11</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-python</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-jmx</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.11</exclude>

                                <!-- Also exclude very big transitive dependencies of Flink

                                WARNING: You have to remove these excludes if your code relies on other
                                versions of these dependencies.

                                -->

                                <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-compiler</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-reflect</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-actor_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-remote_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.data-artisans:flakka-slf4j_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>io.netty:netty-all</exclude>
                                <exclude>io.netty:netty</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload</exclude>
                                <!--<exclude>org.apache.avro:avro</exclude>-->
                                <exclude>commons-collections:commons-collections</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-compress</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.tukaani:xz</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.objenesis:objenesis</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.twitter:chill-java</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang</exclude>
                                <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12</exclude>
                                <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-math</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.json</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations</exclude>
                                <exclude>stax:stax-api</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.typesafe:config</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.github.scopt:scopt_*</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-io:commons-io</exclude>
                                <exclude>commons-cli:commons-cli</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.apache.flink:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <!-- exclude shaded google but include shaded curator -->
                                    <exclude>org/apache/flink/shaded/com/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>web-docs/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <!-- If you want to use ./bin/flink run <quickstart jar> uncomment the following lines.
                        This will add a Main-Class entry to the manifest file -->
                        <!--
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>de.hska.stcs.cep.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        -->
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source> <!-- If you want to use Java 8, change this to "1.8" -->
                <target>1.8</target> <!-- If you want to use Java 8, change this to "1.8" -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


    <!-- If you want to use Java 8 Lambda Expressions uncomment the following lines -->
    <!--
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
                        <version>0.21.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.4,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>single</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    -->
</build>
```

**UPDATE**: I build flink 1.3 from source and updated the avro version (from 1.7.7 to 1.8.1) in the project's pom.xml and it seems to work for now. Still unsure why it's not working when building the fat jar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920543/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-in-flink)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try putting the avro jar in the /lib folder.

Comment: That works. However, I need to manually copy the avro package to all /lib folders on all nodes which is generally not recommended (see [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/linking.html)). By explicitly excluding the avro package in the build instructions of the pom.xml I thought my code would ship and use Avro 1.8.1. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

try to use latest version of avro

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Still the same error. [avro-builder](https://github.com/smueller18/avro-builder/blob/master/pom.xml) package and [flink-serlialization](https://github.com/smueller18/flink-serialization/blob/master/pom.xml) package both use Avro 1.8.1.